# How to uninstall 16.04 and reinstall 14.04

Tags: 16.04, uninstall

I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 in August.  I have not been able to use my desktop, or at least the GUI, since. Thank God I have a laptop which still uses 14.04.

I have read a lot of material, on a lot of subjects trying to fix this problem, but looking at the GRUB list, there are a lot of things wrong with the upgrade.  I'll have to learn computer science from scratch to fix this.

In the meantime, I would like to use my desktop again. Hence the question.

By the way, the computer has not been able to read the DVD drive or the USB drives since the upgrade,so the usual rescue approaches are unavailable.

So, using the command-line, how do I replace 16.04 with 14.04.

I am using AMD-64 architecture.

Comment: You should be still boot from DVD and / or USB, by changing the BIOS setting, or by by selecting "boot drive selection option" at the time of booting, by pressing F12 or some such key at the time of booting.

Comment: Personally I doubt that bugs in version 16.04 are your problem; it's more likely that the upgrade caused the bugs.  (I got burned also.)  I'd recommend installing 16.04 from scratch, rather than trying to go back to 14.04.  Here's an [Ubuntu Forums thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1946145) with more information and instructions.

Comment: These comments are interesting, but they ignore the fact that I no longer have the ability to boot from or access my dvd or usb drives, as a result of the so-called upgrade.  I could try a floppy, just in case that interface still works, but from a floppy would be interesting.

Comment: used a live usb to install a full version of 16.04 in a new partition. Now all I have to do is turn the old flag on the partition where the corrupted upgrade is.